# Xpath issue, trying to locate a element based off the results of another

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to use this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

from textblob import TextBlob


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/home/littlejiver/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://zooqle.com/movie/toy-story-l9.html?tg=7")

torrent_titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="body_container"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')

torrent_found_on_zooqle = False

for title in torrent_titles:
    title_to_check = TextBlob(title.text)
    if title_to_check.detect_language() == "en":
        if int(title.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body_container"]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/div[1]').text) == 10:
            title.click()
            torrent_found_on_zooqle = True
            break
        else:
            print("not enough seeds")
```

to check the red highlighted element if it passes then give me the yellow highlighted information if it qualifies

[image]

right now, what my code is doing is checking if the title is English and then checking the seeds but for the first row in the table and not the corresponding one.

any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Thank you!

littlejiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to xpath from the a tag so you weren't correctly going to the next element.

```
torrent_titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')

torrent_found_on_zooqle = False

for title in torrent_titles:
    title_to_check = TextBlob(title.text)
    if title_to_check.detect_language() == "en":
        if title.find_element_by_xpath("following::td[@class='text-nowrap']/div[1]/div[1]").text == '10':
            title.click()
            torrent_found_on_zooqle = True
            break
        else:
            print("not enough seeds")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid using xpaths so long and brittle. Something like: `//a[@class='small']` and `//div[contains(@class, 'progress-bar smaller')]` might work better in this case.

But either way, if your torrent_titles does get the full list of elements, then you could try something like this:

```
torrent_titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="body_container"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')
torrent_seeders = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="body_container"]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/div[1]').text
torrent_found_on_zooqle = False
for i in range(len(torrent_titles)):
    if int(torrent_seeders[i]) == 10:
        torrent_titles[i].click()
        torrent_found_on_zooqle = True
        break
    else:
        print("not enough seeds")
```

I hope this helps. I haven't tested this so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I think you are correct about simplifying the xpaths (still learning lol)